# GMaps API V3 - Drag inside - and Drop outside of a map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, drag-and-drop, maps

i am looking for an on possibility to click on a marker inside of a Google map, drag it and drop it outside the map on an seperate object (using jquery for drop-event listening). Is there such a possibility? Maybe with another maps provider?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The marker icon is an image. I am thinking using jQuery draggable to clone the image and create a new element on page, then drag that around.